# How to find a percentile that can maximize the correlation coefficient between two vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two continuous vectors such like:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 y = rnorm(100,3,5))
with(df, cor(x,y))
```

My question is how to find a percentile of `x` so that to maximize the absolute correlation of x and y such that:

```
perc <- quantile(df$x, 0.3)
df1 <- subset(df, x > perc)
with(df1, cor(x,y))
```

Namely how to find `perc`?

Comment: You need to rethink the question. As soon a x and y contain only 2 element the correlation will be either 1 or -1.

Comment: No, you may have not understood my question. x and y are still continuous.

Comment: You have not understood my comment. Any subset of 2 number will yield a perfect correlation. mean(replicate(
  1e3,
  abs(cor(runif(2), runif(2)))
))

Comment: Note that subsetting `x` without subsetting `y` is dangerous. `x` will be recycled so that it is as long as `y`!

Comment: @Thierry and DavidZ : See plot in my answer for what he is warning against.

Comment: Thanks @A.Webb for pointing out the global maximum. I have adjusted my solution accordingly, adding the constraint that at least three people need to be in the sample.

Comment: The correlations being found here are spurious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why not take your question literally, and just search for it? For instance, try:

```
findperc <- function(prop, dat) {
  perc <- quantile(dat$x, prop)  
  with(subset(dat, dat$x > perc), abs(cor(x,y)))
}

optimize(findperc, lower=0, upper=1, maximum=T, dat=df)
```

This defines a function that computes the absolute correlation between your vectors based on the corresponding percentile (which here is a single value), just as in your example code. And then I feed this function to a linear optimizer which searches for the input that produces the maximum value for the output.

---

Edit: Thanks to @A. Webb's answer I learned that `optimize` uses a gradient search as opposed to a grid search. I thought that this was the main difference between `optim` and `optimize`, a clearly wrong assumption I should have checked myself. However, just to provide a solution using grid search that will get you closer to the global maximum, one could use the following:

```
 x <- seq(0,0.97,0.01)
 x[which.max(sapply(x, findperc, dat=df))]
```

Note that I have cut `x` here at 97%. This ensures that at least 3 people are left in the sample (given a sample size of 100).

Comment: Thanks, @coffeinjunky!

Answer (score 3):

This problem is ill defined. Take your example data set and the function you want to find the maximum of (copied from @coffeinjunky):

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                 y = rnorm(100,3,5))

findperc <- function(prop, dat) {
  perc <- quantile(dat$x, prop)  
  with(subset(dat, dat$x > perc), abs(cor(x,y)))
}
```

Now plot the result of `findperc` for percentiles between 0 and 1.

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)
plot(x,sapply(x,findperc,df),type="l")
```

The circled point indicates that found by `optimize` as in @coffeinjunky's answer. This is clearly only a local maximum. The applicability of the warning from @Thierry, "You need to rethink the question. As soon a x and y contain only 2 element the correlation will be either 1 or -1", should be apparent on the right hand side of the plot.

In general, the fact that you are getting moderate to high correlations when starting with independently generated random variables should warn you that your results are spurious and method suspect.

[image: plot of findperc at percentiles between 0 and 1]